# Alguien puede ayudarme con este código? Unity y C#

Tags: c#, unity3d

Estoy realizando un videojuego en Unity y el ataque de mi personaje principal ha dejado de funcionar.

Nose que es lo que esta mal o que no estoy siendo capaz de ver...

Os dejo el codigo del script ControlPersonaje por si alguien me puede ayudar o orientar.

En el if del Input de Fire1 no entra, pero no logro ver porque.

Quizas el problema está en otra parte del codigo o incluso en el return del if anterior, pero no se como solucionarlo.

Os paso el metodo Update.

Gracias de antemano.

```
public class ControlPersonaje : MonoBehaviour
{

private void Update()
{
    slider.value = energy;
    txt.text = energy.ToString();

    if (!anim.GetCurrentAnimatorStateInfo(0).IsName("Muriendo"))
    {
        if (energy <= 0)
        {
            energy = 0;

            anim.SetTrigger("morir");
            aSource.PlayOneShot(dying);
        }
        else
        {
            return;
        }
    }

    if (Mathf.Abs(Input.GetAxis("Fire1")) > 0.01f)
    {
        //Debug.Log ("En Fire1");
        if (enFire1 == false)
        {
            enFire1 = true;
            Debug.Log("Shoot");
            anim.SetTrigger("atacar");
            if (ctrArbol != null)
            {
                if (ctrArbol.GolpeMainCharacter())
                {

                    if (energy > 100)
                        energy = 100;
                }
                else
                {
                    //Cambio por el metodo de incrementar energia
                    IncrementarEnergia(costeGolpeAlArbol * -1);
                    aSource.PlayOneShot(golpeandoUnArbol);
                }
            }
            else
            {
                //Cambio por el metodo de incrementar energia
                IncrementarEnergia(costeGolpeAlAire * -1);
            }
            // Esto es mejor en la salida del estado Attack
            //hacha.GetComponent<CircleCollider2D>().enabled = true;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        enFire1 = false;
    }


}
```

Comment: ¿Qué ha dejado de funcionar? ¿Cuál era el comportamiento anterior, cuál es el actual y cuál es el esperado? ¿Qué falla del código compartido? ¿Qué ruta sigue la ejecución? ¿Sobre que objeto(s) se aplica el script que contiene el código compartido?

Comment: Hola buenas, disculpa por mi primer post escaso de info. Lo que ha pasado es que antes mi personaje atacaba en base a la animación llamada "atacar" cuando presionaba el boton izquierdo del mouse, ahora mismo no hace nada cuando lo presiono. En el codigo compartido no falla nada en base a Unity o Visual Studio, no me marcan ningun error y eso es lo que mas me confunde. El script se aplica sobre el objeto Player que es el MainCharacter de mi proyecto.

Comment: Puduieras poner un    `Debug.Log ("Shoot"); `  antes de  `anim.SetTrigger("atacar");` solo para que corrobores que se ejecuta esa parte... una vez que corrobores eso podemos descartar otras cosas...

Comment: No entra en el if del Input, ya probé a poner un debug y nada. Voy a pasar todo mi codigo del script ControlPersonaje a ver si así se puede identificar mejor el problema. Muchas gracias en cualquier caso.

Comment: Cuando te refieres a **no entra en el if input** te refieres al if(Math.Abs...)? Si es así siempre se va por el  else?

Comment: @JuanCarlosGuibovich Hola, sí me refería al if(Math.Abs..). No entra ahí, ni en el else. Perdonar mi ignorancia pero soy bastante novato en esto.

Comment: Vale, ya lo conseguí hacer funcionar. El problema efectivamente estaba en el return del anterior if, el de la animación de morir. Ese return impedia que se ejecutase el if del "Fire1". Muchas gracias a todos.